# The $3$-form $\text{trace}(\left[x,y \right] \cdot z)$ on $SO(n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms

I'm finishing a course project on Lie groups and I'm quite stuck with the following problem.

> Consider the trilinear, antisymmetric form $\omega (x,y,z) = \text{trace}(\left[ x,y \right] \cdot z )$ on the space $\text{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. (Here "$\cdot$" denotes matrix multiplication, and $\left[ \cdot, \cdot \right]$ denotes the matrix commutator.)
>
> *i)* Prove that $\omega$ is defines a $3$-form on $G = SO(n)$.
>
> *ii)* For $G = SO(3)$, prove that $\omega$ is closed, but not exact.

**Some background:** Part 1 seems like a very strange question to me since, well, any element of $SO(n)$ is an $n\times n$-matrix, so $\omega$ is already a $3$-form on a space that contains $SO(n)$, so what is the problem? My professor gave a hint that it would be enough to prove that $\omega$ is invariant under translations, but I'm not sure how that helps, and I'm not even sure how to prove that.

Given part 1 and given that $\omega$ is invariant under translations, I feel part 2 is quite simple: $\omega$ is a $3$-form on a $3$-dimensional manifold, so $d \omega$ is a $4$-form on the manifold, hence the $0$ form. But $\omega$ cannot be exact since, if $\omega = d \eta$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{SO(3)} \omega = \int_{SO(3)} d \eta = \int_{\partial SO(3)} \eta = 0 \quad \quad (*)
\end{align*}
since $SO(3)$ has no boundary. On the other hand, since $\omega$ is non-zero and translation invariant, $\omega$ must equal $c \cdot dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ for some constant $c \neq 0$, which contradicts $(*)$.

**My question(s):** What is there even to prove in part 1? And how can one realize that $\omega$ must be invariant under translations?

Any thoughts and hints are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: You are correct that a $3$-form on $GL(n)$ restricts to a $3$-form on $SO(n)\subset GL(n)$. Perhaps your professor wants you to check that it's a (left- or right- or bi-) invariant $3$-from on $SO(n)$?

Comment: Yes, that  sounds like a reasonable explanation.

Comment: I don't think that the idea is to view $\omega$ as a 3-form on $GL(n)$ and restrict to $SO(n)$, but rather to restrict it to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ and then considering the induced left invariant form on $SO(n)$. (So "translation" should be interpreted in the sense of Lie groups.) From this it follows that for $n=3$, the integral is non-trivial. (The form is also closed but not  exact for higher $n$, but this needs a different proof based on the fact that it is bi-invariant.)

Comment: @AndreasCap So I should think of the situation so that form is initially defined on $T_e G = \mathfrak{so}(n)$, and then if $(\ell_g)^* \omega = \omega$ for all $g \in G$, I can move $\omega$ around so that it's defined on all of $G$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. There is a unique form which is left invariant and whose value in $e$ is $\omega$.

Comment: @AndreasCap I see. Thank you! The form $\omega_g = \ell_{g^{-1}}^* (\omega)$ seems to do the job(?), but I wonder how it could be described more explicitly (although I don't really think that is strictly necessary). Do you have any thoughts on this?